# Como utilizar css em lista de arrays ou objects em React native

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

ola boa tarde sou novo no react native tei  como usa css nesse tipo assim

```
const DATA = [
    {
        pergunt: `O seu Detector de Gases com monitoramento on line se 
        encontra em condições padrão de uso e em comunicação com o 
       sistema de acompanhamento Inet Control?`,
    },
   ];
```

no caso somente  nas palavras  **monitoramento e acompanhamento**  queria adiciona nessas palavras estilo italico ou bold sacaram

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Se você quer usar HTML no React Natvive precisa usar um componente que suporte HTML. Você pode dar uma olhada neste aqui https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-render-html

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim, utilizando o component  to React Native ( O exemplo abaixo exemplifica como deixar o texto em negrito, itálico e sublinhado ).

```
<Text style={styles.bold}>I'm bold!</Text>
<Text style={styles.italic}>I'm italic!</Text>
<Text style={styles.underline}>I'm underlined!</Text>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bold: {fontWeight: 'bold'},
    italic: {fontStyle: 'italic'},
    underline: {textDecorationLine: 'underline'}
})
```

Comment: grato pela resposta mais so queria estilizar uma string caso seria somente a palavras monitoramento e acompanhamento ..